# Rounding floats in C# WITHOUT using Math.Round

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding

https://github.com/TelerikAcademy/CSharp-Part-1/blob/master/4.%20Console%20In%20and%20Out/README.md

Problem 3, here's my code:

```
Console.Write("Please enter circle radius: ");
double Radius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("\nPerimeter is: {0:F2}", Math.PI*2*Radius);
Console.WriteLine("Area is: {0:F2}", Math.PI*Radius*Radius);
```

Problem 5, here's my code:

```
Console.Write("Enter first number: ");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (a<0 || a>500)
{
    Console.WriteLine("number A out of bounds!");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

Console.Write("Enter second number: ");
float b = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter third number: ");
float c = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

string ahex = a.ToString("X");
string abin = Convert.ToString(a, 2);
abin = abin.PadLeft(10,'0');

//float brounded = Math.Round(b,2);

//float crounded = Math.Round(c,3);

Console.WriteLine(ahex + " |" + abin + "| " + "{0:0.00}|" + "{1:0.000} |", b, c);
```

For some reason, when in problem 5 I try to use the `{0:2F}` format that I used in problem 3, the output converts my float to hexadecimal notation. This makes zero sense. As a result, I have to use the `{0:0.00}` format. What goes wrong?

Comment: I think you want `{0:F2}` not `{0:2F}`

Comment: Also, either use composite formatting or use string concatenation in your `WriteLine`, mixing the two is just ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `F2` according to [MSDN Standard numeric Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)